# Conditional based on the age of an entry

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals, date, spam

I want to embed a template if the entry_date of an entry is less than a certain age, and display something else otherwise.  Is there a good way to do this natively?  With addons?  I tried the timespan plugin, but the documentation seems to halfway be for a previous version of the app that was named differently, and none of it seems to actually work.

In my specific case I want to embed the template if the entry is less than 3 years old, but otherwise display a message that we don't provide this information for old entries.

I think the most common useful case for this is a contact form (or comment field though there are addons for expiring comments) for each entry in a channel and you start to get hammered with spam on old entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two options you could try. Vim Interactive has a date plug-in, [DT Plugin](http://viminteractive.com/software/dt_plugin/), that lets you set the year offset within the plug-in tag itself. Solspace also has a date plug-in called [Date Field Filter](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/date_field_filter/). To set the offset you require would mean you need to turn on PHP in your templates. I'd recommend trying Vim's plug-in first and see of this solves your problem before going down the Solspace route. Both plug-ins are free so there's no reason not to give them a shot.

update from further expirimentation:

```
embed tag:{embed="grp/tmp" ent_date="{exp:dt set="{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}" ee_format=“true" format="%y%m%d"}" 3_years="{exp:dt year="-3" ee_format=“true" format="%y%m%d"}"}
```

to add variables to the embedded template, and then:

```
{if {embed:ent_date} < {embed:3_years}}Old Entry Message{if:else}New Entry Content{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, if I need to turn on PHP I can do the whole thing myself, I'm hoping to find someway to avoid that.

Comment: Just looked into this further, DT Plugin was neat in that I could make the following code: `If {exp:dt set="{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}" ee_format=“true" format="%y%m%d"} is less than  {exp:dt year="-3" ee_format=“true" format="%y%m%d"} this program is older than 3 years old` Which explains what logically I'm trying to do, but I haven't managed to get the conditional part figured out.  I guess maybe I can send the two numbers to the embed and do the conditional there, I may give that a try.  The second one doesn't do what I want because I want to filter certain content, not the whole entry.

Comment: Stuart, I took your answer a little bit further and got it to work.  Can you add this to your answer and then I'll accept it?:

Comment: embed tag:`{embed="grp/tmp" ent_date="{exp:dt set="{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}" ee_format=“true" format="%y%m%d"}" 3_years="{exp:dt year="-3" ee_format=“true" format="%y%m%d"}"}` to add variables to the embedded template, and then: `{if {embed:ent_date} < {embed:3_years}}Old Entry Message{if:else}New Entry Content{/if}`

Answer (score 1):

you could check if the current date minus the date of the entry exceeds 3 years:

```
{if '{current_time format="%U"}' - '{entry_date format="%U"}' >= 31536000}
    // entry is older than 3 years
{/if}
```

note that this isn't a 100% correct, as the '31536000' is the amount of seconds in a normal year, so this neglects leap-years..

Comment: Hi janvi I don't think you can do that.  My testing has not shown mathematical operations to work in conditionals, just comparison operators.

Comment: While this isn't my exact problem, you saved me from further troubleshooting setting and testing Stash variables when what I really wanted was `{if '{entry_date format="%Y%m%d"}' != '{edit_date format="%Y%m%d"}'}`

Answer (score 0):

Having had a quick look at the [Timespan](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/timespan) source code I think you'd want to try something like this if you haven't already:

```
{exp:timespan date="{entry_date}"}
    {if '{timespan:years}' < '3'}
        DOSTUFF
    {if:else}
        OTHERSTUFF
    {/if}
{/exp:timespan}
```

I'm not sure why their sample code includes references to `{exp:ellapsed}` - maybe it was an earlier name for the addon.

Comment: Thanks Dom, I did the same thing (look at the source code) and started by just trying to get it to output the years. When that failed I decided to stop bothering with an obviously poorly maintained plugin.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I'll leave my answer up just to save anyone else wasting their time on that addon.